# What's the best combination of layouts to use to create this effect?

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to create a program with some kind of list which is dropped down when you are clicking in the desired *category* and reveal some items in there.

I am new to layouts and XML editing, so I would love to have a tip where to start with.

I tried `RelativeLayout` but then I am stacked.

[image: Layout sample.]

**I don't want you to write the code for me**, just some suggestions for what Layout is better to use and I will do my research for that. Thanks.

Comment: @Blackbelt well that's something I didn't know that exists. I think it's gonna work. Thanks man.

Comment: @Blackbelt you want to write it as an answer so you are gonna get the credits, or it's ok if I accept the answer of Kelevandos?

Comment: accept the provided one

Comment: Thanks @Blackbelt, that was nice :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ExpandableListView` class, with a custom view for the children :-)